# Call method after changing preferences in Android

Tags: android, android-preferences

i have my preferences like this:

settings.xml:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/sectionOneTitle" >
        <EditTextPreference
                android:title="@string/setModuleName"
                android:summary="@string/setModuleNameSum"
                android:key="moduleID"/>
    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/sectionTwoTitle" >
        <EditTextPreference
                android:title="@string/setPhoneNumber"
                android:summary="@string/setPhoneNumberSum"
                android:key="phoneNumber"/>
    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/sectionThreeTitle" >
        <CheckBoxPreference android:title="@string/setSmsSend"
            android:key="setSmsSend" android:summary="@string/setSmsSendSum" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Settings Activity

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    }
}
```

Now i need to get a method in my MAINActivity called when the checkbox is set or unset. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: is this a preference fragment or preference activity

Comment: this is my settings.xml see the edit

Comment: yes I realize that but what are you using to show it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add an `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` to your activity:

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener;
...

public class MAINActivity extends Activity {
    private OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener =
        new OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
                if (key.equals("setSmsSend") {
                    smsSendPrefChanged(); // the function you want called
                }
            }
        };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        prefs.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: How does the OnSharedPreferenceChangedListener class looks like?

Comment: @progNewFag - Sorry about that--there was a typo in the name. It's `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` ("Change", not "Changed"). Consult [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html) for more info. I added an `import` statement to the example to clarify.

Answer (score -1):

Using *PreferenceFragmentCompat*

```
public class FragmentSettings
extends PreferenceFragmentCompat
implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener


@Override
public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.app_preferences);

    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

    switch(key)
    {
        case "KEY1":
            // DO STUFF
            break;

        case "KEY2":
            // DO STUFF
            break;
    }
}
```